# Java program will not recognize sentinel value

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, do-while, sentinel

My program accept input data from a user (up to 20 values) and calculate the average/find the distance from the average. If the user enters "9999" when no numbers have been added yet it will display an error message and tell the user to re-enter a value. Otherwise entering "9999" will collect what the user has entered and do its calculations. My program will have to collect all 20 inputs from the user and also ignore when the value "9999" is entered completely but, it will do the other calculations correctly. I'm not sure why its not recognizing my sentinel value whatsoever.

```
package labpack;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        double [] numbers = new double[20];
        double sum = 0;
        int sentValue = 9999;

        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the numbers you want up to 20");

        do {
            for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { 
                if (numbers[0] == sentValue){
                    System.out.println("Error: Please enter a number");
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    numbers[i] = input.nextDouble(); 
                    sum += numbers[i];
                }
            } 

            while (i<numbers.length && numbers[i]!=sentValue); //part of do-while loop

            //calculate average and distance from average
            double average = (sum / i);
            System.out.println("This is your average:" + average);

            for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { //Display for loop
                double diffrence = (average-numbers[i]);
                System.out.println("This is how far number " +numbers[i] +" is from the average:" + diffrence);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried running it in a debugger?

Comment: BTW, `return` from `main` will terminate your program

Comment: There are some design flaws here 1) the inner for loop executes for all 20 numbers since there is no test for the sentinel inside the for loop 2) the inner for loop overwrites numbers[0] 3) I don't think you need both the outer do while loop AND the inner for loop to solve the problem as stated.

Comment: So i switched return to break and moved my code around. I think I need the do-while because it needs to keep checking if the user put '9999' in after the initial first number. I could be wrong. I'll edit and update my code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without doing the do-while and doing while instead.

```
if (numbers[0]== sentValue){
            System.out.println("Error: Please enter a number");
            break;
```

Here you are trying to compare the value without initializing the array with the user input.

This can be done in a much simple way :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        double [] numbers =new double[10];
        double sum =0;
        double sentValue=9999;
        int count = 0;
        System.out.println(numbers.length);
        System.out.print("Enter the numbers you want up to 20");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (i<numbers.length){
            double temp = input.nextDouble();
            if (temp >= sentValue){
                if(i==0){
                    System.out.println("Error Message Here");
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }//if
            else {
                numbers[i] = temp;
                sum += numbers[i];
                i++;
                count++;
            }
        } //part of while loop*/

        //calculate average and distance from average
        double average=(sum/i);
        System.out.println("This is your average:" + average);

        for (i=0;i < count;i++){ //Display for loop
            double diffrence = (average-numbers[i]);
            System.out.println("This is how far number " +numbers[i] +" is from the average:" + diffrence);
        }//for loop
    }//main bracket

}//class lab4 bracket
```

You need to store the value of the *input.nextDouble()* into a variable because when the compiler reads *input.nextDouble()*, each time it will ask the user for an input.

PS. You dont need to re-initialize this part :

```
java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
```

The above line can simply be written as :

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

because you already imported Scanner.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi! It helps but I want the program to keep adding to the array of 'numbers' until the value 9999 is entered. Then it will do the calculations with the number of inputted values. Even if  they only entered 2 values or 20 values. But if they enter 9999 for the first value it will display "In order to do the calculations you must first enter at least one number"

Comment: Check out the updated code now. 
Introduced a variable *count* which keeps a count of how many values were added to the array. Then runs the array till the count and displays the differences for the values only entered by the user.

Comment: Works great! I didn't think I needed a count variable. I never knew how to only display the inputted numbers from an array. I always thought you would have to use all 20 or else they would just display 0's.  This helped me very much and it will definitely help me in the future as well. Thank you!